kubuntu 24.02 kernel 6.8.0-41-generic freezing
At least once a day, the system freezes at the terminal forcing a reboot.
Unable to view any of the system metrics to get an idea of what processes have run amuck for any clues.
What logs should I be looking at for insight into what is happening?
